# How do I estimate the motion of a rigid body from a sequence of images?

Tags: cv.computer-vision

I have just recently started studying computer vision, and I wanted to find ways to compute the translational and rotational motion from a sequence of images alone. Could someone explain how this would work, and what are the steps which are needed to do this, so that it may fit into a code, and what prerequisites do I need to implement it properly? I was thinking of trying to use Horn-and-Schunk Optical Flow to compute image motion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn%E2%80%93Schunck_method I don't think you will get answer here unless you frame it as a complexity problem!